# Jmeter: javaRequest issue

Tags: java, request, jmeter

I have a class from which I am sending request to remote server and getting response.
The type of content is `application/json`.
My class extends from AbstractJavaSamplerClient, and I have override 4 methods.
I have made jar file from this and past it in `jakarta-jmeter-2.4/lib/ext` folder.
When I press "Run" I get an exception and I find out the its come from my JSONObject.
When I added comments in front of that object I get exception in objects connected with HTTPRequest.

I have downloaded packages from [here](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) and past jar files into `/ext` folder. But that didn't get me some result.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: user726637: not only the message, the complete stack trace please.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
 at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:4)
 at android_test.SenderTest.SignIn(SenderTest.java:114)
 at android_test.SenderTest.runTest(SenderTest.java:55)
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler.sample(JavaSampler.java:161)
 at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:348)
 at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:243)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON parsing throws error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560332/json-parsing-throws-error)